# KafkaIO Connector/Apache Beam Transform "go" SDK Available?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am working on building a data ingestion pipeline using Apache Beam "go" SDK.

My pipeline is to consume data from Kafka queue and persist the data to Google Cloud Bigtable (and/or to another Kafka topic).

So far, I have not been able to find a Kafka IO Connector (also known as Apache I/O Transform) written in "go" (I was able to find a java version, however).

Here's link to supported Apache Beam built-in I/O transforms:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/

I am looking for the "go" equivalent of the following Java code:

```html
    pipeline.apply("kafka_deserialization", KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
        .withBootstrapServers(KAFKA_BROKER)
        .withTopic(KAFKA_TOPIC)
        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(CONSUMER_CONFIG)
        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
        .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class))
```

Do you have any information on the availability of KafkaIO Connector "go" SDK/library?

Comment: There's quite a few of them out there. Last I checked, this one wraps around the excellent librdkafka, so should be quite decent [confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go). It's started by the same person who wrote the C/C++ kafka library BTW. PS: This question is likely to be closed, because you're asking for an off-site resource (check the help section as to why this is considered off-topic)

Comment: @Elias That's not for Beam, though

Comment: Thank you @EliasVanOotegem for the comments.  I've updated my post with more detail.  Any information on this topic would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Beam is open source... [Have you searched Github](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io)?

Answer (score 1):

@cricket_007 In case you are also curious, I received the following update from Robert Burke (rebo@google.com) who is in the Apache Beam team:

```
There presently isn't a Kafka transform for Go. 

The Go SDK is still experimental, largely due to scalable IO support, which is why the Go SDK isn't represented in the built-in io page.

There's presently no way for an SDK user to write a Streaming source in the Go SDK, since there's no mechanism for a DoFn to "self terminate" bundles, such as to allow for scalability and windowing from streaming sources. 

However, SplittableDoFns are on their way, and will eventually be the solution for writing these.

At present, the Beam Go SDK IOs haven't been tested and vetted for production use. Until the initial SplittableDoFn support is added to the Go SDK, Batch transforms cannot split, and can't scale beyond a single worker thread. This batch version should land in the next few months, and the streaming version land a few months after that, after which a Kafka IO can be developed. 

I wish I had better news for you, but I can say progress is being made.

Robert Burke
```

Comment: Is there any link to this conversation? I want to see if there is any update on this.